# Does Calendula ointment or cream promote healing of scrapes/cuts/burns?

Tags: natural-remedies, homeopathy

1. From http://www.boironusa.com/products/calendula-cream/:

   > **USES**: Helps promote healing of minor burns and cuts, scrapes, skin irritations and sunburn
   >
   > **ACTIVE INGREDIENT**: Calendula officinalis 1X HPUS-10% - Healing agent
   >
   > **INACTIVE INGREDIENTS**: Caprylyl glycol; Carbomer; Cetyl palmitate; EDTA disodium; Glycerin; Lauroyl macrogolglycerides; Pegoxol-7 stearate; Purified water; Sodium hydroxide; Sorbic acid
   > 1,2-hexanediol
2. From http://www.boironusa.com/products/calendula-ointment/

   > **USES**: ... Helps promote healing of minor burns, scrapes and cuts
   >
   > **ACTIVE INGREDIENT**: Calendula officinalis 1X HPUS-4% - Healing agent
   >
   > **INACTIVE INGREDIENTS**: White petrolatum USP

Is there ***evidence*** that this creme and/or ointment: "Helps promote healing of minor burns and cuts, scrapes, skin irritations and sunburn"?

Specifically, is there any ***testing*** showing whether:

- there is efficacy compared to no treatment
- there is efficacy compared to creme/ointment made from identical inactive ingredients only.

**NOTES**:

- I'm looking for answers related to results of ***testing*** of this specific product(s), NOT general discussion of "this can't work because homeopathy was proven to not work".
- In case the text and the company name aren't a dead giveaway, " 1X HPUS" is supposed to mean that the active ingredient is a homeopathic remedy (*but see @Fabian's comment below*).
- I lumped them together since they seem to have the similar active ingredients; I will accept the answer which pertains to testing either one of those, or both.
- Preference is double-blind randomized testing. Duh.

Comment: 1X is a 1/10 dilution, so this is only homeopathic in name. There is still a potentially active ingredient in a significant concentration in there.

Comment: @Fabian - fair enough. I'm more interested in efficacy than the reasons for it :)

Comment: Also, immediate +50 bonus to any answer pointing to the fact that [Calendula produces money](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Marigold)...

Comment: Alright, I've found a couple studies that show that *Calendula officinalis* can be effective as a anti-inflamatory, anti-viral and anti-genotoxic. Does it have to be specific to just this product or are you willing take a slightly more general answer?

Comment: @RobZ - sorry, specific. I'm skeptical of Boiron's claim of that particular product, not calendula in general.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for results on a specific product the best that can be said is that the efficacy is **unknown with some positive evidence**, since there has been at least one study that used this specific product.

[Phase III Randomized Trial of Calendula Officinalis Compared With Trolamine for the Prevention of Acute Dermatitis During Irradiation for Breast Cancer](http://jco.ascopubs.org/content/22/8/1447.full#ref-15) was published in 2004 by American Society of Clinical Oncology and had the following to say,

> Calendula (Pommade au Calendula par Digestion; calendula extract
>   ointment; Boiron Ltd, Levallois-Perret, France) is fabricated from a
>   plant of the marigold family, Calendula officinalis. The digest is
>   obtained by incubation at 75°C in petroleum jelly to extract the
>   liposoluble components of the plant. Calendula is commercialized in
>   France for adjuvant treatment of irritant dermatitis, skin lesions,
>   and superficial burns. In a randomized, open, parallel study with 156
>   patients of the effectiveness of calendula for the local management of
>   second- and third-degree burns, it was significantly better tolerated
>   than Elase (a proteolytic ointment; Pfizer, New York, NY) and
>   petroleum jelly, and marginally significantly better than petroleum
>   jelly alone for healing.

Concluding that,

> This large randomized study demonstrated that a nonsteroid topical
>   agent was significantly effective in preventing mild to severe
>   radiation-induced dermatitis during radiotherapy for breast cancer.
>   Calendula was statistically significantly superior to trolamine for
>   the primary end point, prevention of skin toxicity of RTOG grade 2 or
>   higher, and for all the secondary end points (including allergy,
>   interruption of treatment, patient satisfaction for relief of pain,
>   and dermatitis), with the exception of ease of application, which was
>   considered by the patients to be more difficult with calendula than
>   with trolamine. The quantity of agent used was significantly smaller
>   with calendula than with trolamine, although this would not lead to a
>   cost reduction, given that the price of calendula is at present twice
>   that of trolamine.

However, [systematic reviews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_review) citing the above article ([1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2913836/), [2](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00520-006-0063-4), [3](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2133.2011.10457.x/abstract)) seem to have mixed at best feelings at best although the search I did didn't seem to have many that called out *Calendula officinalis* as a category on its own.

Comment: "marginally significantly better" - did they quantify that?

Comment: @DVK - I thought that phrasing was weird as well. There is a discussion of the maths, but reskimming the paper I can't tell if they quantify it or not.